# Select/alter range of values in jquery function

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is the code

```
$('#printlocs').on('change', function() {
    var selctloc = $('#printlocs').find('option:selected');
    $('#loc1').prop('disabled', selctloc.val() == '0');
    $('#loc2').prop('disabled', selctloc.val() == '0');
    $('#loc3').prop('disabled', selctloc.val() == '0');
    $('#loc4').prop('disabled', selctloc.val() == '0');
});
```

I want to make it so the string with `#loc1` is disabled only when equal to `'0'`, `#loc2` is disabled with `'0' or '1'` and so on, but I can't figure it out. I've tried putting different areas in brackets, using `||`, but nothing is working.

Comment: Please post a complete code example, in this case including the HTML you're using the jQuery on.

Comment: The HTML code wasn't necessary to find a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just check for those values ?

```
$('#printlocs').on('change', function() {
    $('#loc1').prop('disabled', (this.value == '0'));
    $('#loc2').prop('disabled', (this.value == '0' || this.value == '1'));
    $('#loc3').prop('disabled', (this.value == '0' || this.value == '2' || this.value == '3'));
    $('#loc4').prop('disabled', (this.value == '4')); // 4 only ?
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/pwtJ7/)

You do of course need a select element with options that has these values

Comment: Thanks for putting me on the right track. I tried to post the new code but the comment got all messed up. I just had to replace the "this" with my var, since the changes are being made in different selects.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood when you want to disable your options correctly, you could use the fact that the `prop` function also takes a `function` as it's second argument so you could make use of it as well as the starts with selector to simplify your code.

For instance:

```
var val = Number(selctloc.val());

$('[id^=prop]').prop('disabled', function () {
    //get the number of the element out of the id
    var num = Number(this.id.substring(3));

    //disable if the value is smaller than the number
    return val < num;
});
```